# Why does Unity get stuck when it bakes resources?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am trying to open a project in Unity but it is very slow and it says it is "baking resources". How can I make it faster?

Comment: Now it's doing "bake direct". But it's still very slow.

Comment: Get a new computer / use a lighter project / fix your oven / read [ask].

Comment: Short answer : You can't. Long answer : Change the settings in the lighting tab to use lower values for quick baking times. Read the Unity Manual on the new Enlighten lighting system.

Comment: Go to Window - > Lighting and disable all "GI" settings, both baked and precomputed realtime. This will speed your stuff up massively if you don't specifically require the global illumination stuff.

Answer (score 2):

Depends what do you want to achieve.

If the building while doing changes is problematic go to "Window/Ligthing/Scene" and turn the Bake build auto OFF.

If you are making the finall product you may turn the quality of the shadows and light maping down for less details better performance and building time.

"Window/Ligthing/Scene"

1 Turn off "Precomputed Realtime GI" or turn it down to 1.

2 Play with "Baked GI" Resolution.

3 Window/Ligthing/Object select the biggest complexed objects (like terrain) and set the "Scale In lightmap' down a little

4 If you have a lot of static complex items like trees turn the "static" off. A static forrest could build in to 1GB map or a nonstatic one in to 100MB :)

Its always something in exchange, performance/quality/building time/memory...